# SQL query to combine multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-athena

I am writing a query in SQL in AWS Athena and there's a situation for which I am not able to figure out the query.

Suppose, I have data in this format.
[image]

And I want my table in this format.

[image]

Is there a way we can write sql query for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One method is `union all`:

```
select name, idaction_url as idaction
from t
union all
select name, idaction_name
from t
union all
select name, idaction_content_interaction
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is better option but you can transform needed fields to array and then unnest it:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        ('a', 10, 11),
        ('b', 20,21)) AS t (user_id, idaction_1, idaction_2))


SELECT user_id, idaction
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, ARRAY[idaction_1, idaction_2] arr
    FROM dataset)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(arr) as tmp(idaction)
```

| user_id | idaction |
| --- | --- |
| a | 10 |
| a | 11 |
| b | 20 |
| b | 21 |